# (Java) Get window dimensions/position of an external program

Tags: java, windows, position, dimensions

I was curious as to if I could achieve this in Java:

Say there's two open windows. My java program, and "Super Awesome Fun Game". I was wondering if I could get two bits of information from "Super Awesome Fun Game", and parse it into my program. The bits of information are window position, and dimensions.

Is this possible?

Thanks for reading,

-Alex

Comment: Yep, it can be done with JNI or JNA or similar tool. If you search this site on my name and JNA, you'll see this or similar code.

Comment: I'll go check it out, thanks!

Comment: Though please understand that my solution is Windows-specific, and I think that any solution must be OS-specific.

Comment: Oh, I do not plan on making it compatible with other operating systems, it does Windows-Specific features already.